# how to view all the categorical columns and its information using one line of code?

Tags: python, pandas

instead of checking the unique categorical column information column by column, is there a fast way to do it?

```
df.columnA.unique()
df.columnB.unique()
```

If I want to check columns with more than 100, the code I type above is not economic.

Comment: Does `df.agg('nunique').T` do what you're after? Or are you actually after unique values for each column?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to find out the values for each categorical column that I forgot to mention

Comment: `uniques = {colname: df[colname].unique() for colname in df}` then ?

Comment: Or do you mean that each column that's a categorical type, get their accepted values?

Comment: yes, only categorical. very close

Comment: df.describe() may work well for your application in viewing all unique content

Comment: @ZakkYang possible then: `uniques = {colname: df[colname].unique() for colname in df if df[colname].dtype.name == 'category'}` ?

Comment: Hi Naga, not for categorical ones

Comment: Hi Jon, not working.... only get a {} as output

Comment: df.nunique()[df.nunique()==1].index , can you try this which can list all columns which are having one categorical column whole data

Answer (score 1):

Select Categorical columns via [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html). Then use [`pd.Series.cat.categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html):

```
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='category').columns
res = {col: df[col].cat.categories for col in cat_cols}
```

This assumes *all* categories are used for any given series. If this is not the case, you can use [`pd.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
res = {col: df[col].unique() for col in cat_cols}
```

The difference in behaviour is [documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#working-with-categories):

> **Note**: The result of `unique()` is not always the same as `Series.cat.categories`, because `Series.unique()` has a couple of
>   guarantees, namely that it returns categories in the order of
>   appearance, and it only includes values that are actually present.

Comment: @ZakkYang, That's a bit vague. I can't reproduce your problem. That said, this answers your question as stated.

Comment: Might want to make a reference to *The result of unique() is not always the same as Series.cat.categories, because Series.unique() has a couple of guarantees, namely that it returns categories in the order of appearance, and it only includes values that are actually present.* at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html regarding the *This assumes all categories are used for any given series. If this is not the case [...]*

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df.columns:
if df[col].dtype == 'object':
    print('\nColumn Name:', col,)
    print(df[col].value_counts())
```

I found the solution myself...

Comment: If this is the solution that worked for you - it's completely different than the question you asked... a "categorical column" is a completely separate type in pandas... (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

Comment: Hi Jon, you are right. But in practice, we treat most categorical information in the 'object' types, right?

Comment: @ZakkYang, No, I'd say that wrong. Categorical information is usually stored as.. categories. At least, they *should* be for performance and control reasons.